# Can we convert A DXF pattern to Ai with notch marks?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

The notch marks that are added in Lectra files are not visible when the DXF is converted to Ai.
Any way i can get these visible?

Answer (score 1):

Many of us use Illustrator but only a few of us have high end cutting machines, so the chance of finding someone here with Lectra experience is quite low.

Some guesses are possible. You could try to open a simple file and check the layers and appearance panels in Illustrator. You may find objects which exist but have no fill nor stroke, maybe a hidden layer or something else. Without having access to the file it's impossible to say what. There could also be something that Illustrator just skips and you can't see a trace of it in the panels.

Your 2nd option is to try to open it in a CAD program. There are freebies which can open DXFs to some degree. The format isn't stable. Autodesk has been updated regularly to keep its products one step ahead. LibreCAD can also open DXFs. Even Inkscape can open them.

Your 3rd option is to use some online file converter and make a PDF or SVG. Illustrator can open these.

The 4th and most preferable option is to contact cutting machine's support. They should be able and willing to assist. I guess the DXF is an export from some Lectra specific cutting optimization software, so the export must have the right options ON as a starting point to make the export to contain all the correct info. It's even possible that multiple exports are needed to export different layer types, but that's only a guess.

Ask Lectra!

Comment: @Billy Kerr Fine rectification.Thanks again!.

Comment: no problem, it was a good answer anyway! Just needed a few tweaks.